# Failed sent message using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I recently submitted an app to Apple and sadly it was rejected. The reason given was that it has an email to friend feature that wasn't working. (Needless to say, but it works great on my device). I'm using an MFMailComposeViewController, filling in the subject and body and adding an attachment. The user then must take the rest of the action to send. When I asked for elaboration the reviewer said...

> The Emails we have sent with your app are listed in the Gmail, and Yahoo, test accounts "outbox," with an error stating the outgoing mail server could not be reached.

...should this count as an error with my app? I don't actually send the mail, I just use the built in SDK calls to prepare a message. I know an argument of "it's your device" won't really  advance me towards getting my app approved but I really think it's their device.

Can anyone think of any reasons an email would fail with a message like this and of those reasons, anything I could actually do about it?

And now my code...

...where I send the message

```
- (void)sendMail
{
    NSData *vCards = (NSData *)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople((CFArrayRef)self.selections);

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];  
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;  

    [mc setSubject:@"Contact"];

    [mc setMessageBody:@"<p>My message...<p>" isHTML:YES];  
    NSString *label = ([self.selections count] == 1)? (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName([self.selections objectAtIndex:0]): @"Contacts";

    [mc addAttachmentData:vCards mimeType:@"text/x-vcard" fileName:label];

    [self presentModalViewController:mc animated:YES];  
    [mc release];  
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {  
    switch (result) {  
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:  
            NSLog(@"Mail send canceled.");  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:  
            NSLog(@"Mail saved.");  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:  
            NSLog(@"Mail sent.");  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:  
            NSLog(@"Mail send error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);  
            break;  
        default:  
            break;  
    }  
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Now I understand that I'm not actually doing anything useful if the message fails, but should the message even be getting to the user's outbox if it fails at the compose level?

I'm going to submit another version alerting the error details, but I doubt there will be any.

Comment: I have virtually the same code as you in one of my apps and it works fine. This ruling does seem harsh and unrelated to your app. Have you filed an appeal, suggesting that the email accounts on their test device are not well set up?

Comment: The only additional thing I do check if the device can send email, using [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]

Comment: Thanks onnoweb, I just submitted an appeal. Because of the ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople I require iOS 5 anyway, so it should be able to send mail regardless. Will let ya know how it works out.

Comment: The last statement is not true. It might not be able to send mail, if for example the user has not set up an email account. You should really check this. An other thought: where does the label variable come from, and what does it contain? Is there any chance that variable could be empty? Or nil?

Comment: @tonklon, sorry bout that, I removed a bunch of code before posting and didn't see I was using 'label', I've put label's instantiation back now. Also, I'll put the proper checks in for iOS devices without emails.

Comment: That looks very reasonable to me now. I can't think of any reason that  should not work. Let's wait for the outcome of your appeal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last night on my iPhone I got notifications from the iTunesConnect that my app was In Review > Waiting For Review > Processing for App Store > Ready For Sale, all in rapid succession. The Resolution Center has no further notes and I received no other emails from Apple about the issue. I'm happy it all go worked out, but still have a lingering doubt that some edge case bug is going to one-star me to death. Sorry the resolution is so boring.

Here's my app in the store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloner/id483981001?mt=8 (plug). Thanks to everyone for the great suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It could be just a vague rejection reason stemming from the fact that you don't handle the send error. I have a very similar implementation for feedback. I would consider showing an alert saying what the reason is, and for the user to try again. Apple will check you over for just about every possibility.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I've submitted an appeal and they request you don't change the build during the review time. I'm fine if the reason is that I'm not handling errors, but they should state that in the rejection reasoning instead of a vague "email doesn't send" message.

Comment: I would agree. But this is the price we pay to be a member of the cool kids club. ;) Good luck with the appeal.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing, can you try not to send the vcard with it?  tell me if it works...

Comment: During my tests it works fine. Also sending the vCard is a major part of the app so I don't want to submit a version without it.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I added .vcf extension to the fileName (label) and it worked fine... try it, it may be the problem...